# how to save android SharedPreferences using retrofit and get id

Tags: android, validation, authentication, retrofit, sharedpreferences

I made a validation to log in using retrofit, and I have already placed sharedpreferences in the login class and in the second class. can log in, but I can't get the user ID when logging in. There have been various ways but it didn't work. anyone know the solution?

ValidationLogin Class

```
public void LoginUser() {
    //membuat progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("Tunggu proses login ...");
    pDialog.show();

    //mengambil data dari edittext
    final String username = txtusername.getText().toString();
    String password = txtpassword.getText().toString();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL).client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())).build();

    RequestInterface api = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseLogin> call = api.login_member(id, username ,  password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseLogin>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseLogin> call, Response<ResponseLogin> response) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                if(response.body().getResult() != null){

                    // menyimpan login ke session

                    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                    editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                    editor.putString(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    editor.apply();


                    //login start main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUser.this, Second.class);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Selamat datang "+username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Selamat datang "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                    intent.putExtra("id", id);
                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                    intent.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseLogin> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Koneksi internet terputus.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

onCreate

```
// Cek session login jika TRUE maka langsung buka MainActivity
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);
id = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_ID, "id tidak ditemukan");
email = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_EMAIL, "email tidak ditemukan");

if (session) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUser.this, MenuUtama.class);
    intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
    intent.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email);
    intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}

btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String username = txtusername.getText().toString();
        String password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
        if (isEmpty(username))
            txtusername.setError("Username harap diisi");
        else if (isEmpty(password))
            txtpassword.setError("Password harap diisi");

        else
            LoginUser();

        //Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUser.this, Second.class);
        ///startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Second Class

```
sharedpreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(ValidationLogin.my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
id = sharedpreferences.getString("id", "0");
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ini id ke-"+ id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And this respon json, I was struggling to get ID

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "reason": "OK",
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "result": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9.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.zIEhdU5MyNjReG_9_661FWf0_R5eZuJweyl0JNFd7X0"
}
```

Comment: have you checked what this `ValidationLogin.my_shared_preferences` provide you. Might it can be blank. When your activity onCreate then it provide the value.